# Writing logs with Tinylog on Android

Tags: android, android-log, tinylog

I want to save logs on Android using tinylog and I have added dependencies and configuration file. Sometimes the file is created with content and other times the file is empty. It seems like random behavior. Also the app has writing and reading permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have added this on graddle.

```
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog-api:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog-impl:2.1.0'
```

I have put my `tinylog.properties` file inside `src/main/resources`

```
writer1 = logcat
writer1.level = debug

writer2 = rolling file
writer2.level = trace
writer2.format = {date} [{thread}] {level}:\n{message}
writer2.file  = /storage/emulated/0/app/logs/log_{date:yyyyMMdd}.txt
writer2.charset  = UTF-8
writer2.append = true
writer2.policies = daily: 03:00

writingthread = true
```

Comment: Actually, your configuring looks fine. The property `writer2.append = true` does nothing, but this won't be the cause for your issue. Do you use a real phone or an emulator? Is the time unequal 3am? Are the missing log entries output via logcat?

Comment: I have just updated the official Android example (https://github.com/pmwmedia/tinylog-android-example) to use the rolling file writer. Logging works reliable using this example with Android Studio 4.1 and emulated Android 10.

Comment: did you find the solution for this JuanDYB ?